# Upload files to the server within a folder using WebService

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am trying to upload files from windows application to the server within a folder
   using webservice..(Asp.Net,C#)..
   Can any body help me out

Comment: so what is not working? What did you do? ASP or C#? Please eloborate

Comment: How far have you come with the solution before you got stuck?

Comment: could you provide your relevant code an problems?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/wsfileserver.aspx